# How can I add content to an existing JavaScript variable?

Tags: javascript, html

So I want to add content like a string or another variable to a variable that already exists. I know this isn't right, but this is what I have.

```
var variable = "Variable";

function dispVar1() {
    let p = document.createElement("p");

    p.innerHTML = variable;
}

function dispVar2() {
    let p = document.createElement("p");
    let alteredVar = variable + " that has been altered";
    /* Also, could I do "" + variable to make string go before the variable? */

    p.innerHTML = alteredVar;
}
```

```
<input type="button" value="Original" onclick="dispVar1();">
<input type="button" value="Altered" onclick="dispVar2();">
```

Comment: Just use `+=` to concatenate more onto the value.

Comment: Of course you can use `"something" + variable`. Why would the order make a difference?

Comment: See [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make an executable snippet.

Comment: Basically, click on the `[<>]` tool in the toolbar to open the snippet editor.

Comment: plot twist, this question is actually about `innerHTML` and you should use `p.textContent` if you just add some text to it. Its more performant.

Comment: @TheFool Lol not what I was going for but thanks for the advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use the [`+` assignment operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators) to concatenate strings. You can see in the example I am creating a variable `newValue` that concats your original variable plus some additional text:

```js
var variable = "Variable";
var targetEl = document.querySelector('#target');

function dispVar1() {
  target.innerHTML = '';
  let p = document.createElement("p");

  p.innerHTML = variable;
  target.appendChild(p);
}

function dispVar2() {
  target.innerHTML = '';
  let p = document.createElement("p");

  const newValue = variable + ' (here\'s some added text)';
  p.innerHTML = newValue;
  target.appendChild(p);
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Original" onclick="dispVar1();">
<input type="button" value="Altered" onclick="dispVar2();">
<div id="target"></div>
```

Alternatively, you can take advantage of [`String.prototype.concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/concat) to achieve the same thing - but MDN doesn't recommend it:

> It is strongly recommended that the assignment operators (+, +=) are
>   used instead of the concat() method.
>
> According to this [performance test,](https://jsperf.com/concat-vs-plus-vs-join) the assignment operators are several times faster.

Answer (score 0):

Your initial code works:

```
let alteredVar = variable + " that has been altered";
```

An alternative using [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) with placeholders is more fashionable than concatenation because it removes the necessity of escaping certain characters, is more flexible, and arguably more readable:

```
let alteredVar = `${variable} that has been altered`;
```